# How to be thread-safe using INotifyPropertyChanged with no SynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, multithreading, inotifypropertychanged

How do you keep your objects thread-safe that implement INotifyPropertyChanged? I can't use a SynchronizationContext because I need to be able to serialize the object.

```
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
           // What can I add here to make it thread-safe? 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: "I can't use a SynchronizationContext because I need to be able to serialize the object." -- that shouldn't be a problem. Have you marked the field with `[NonSerialized]` and added a `OnDeserializing` method to reset it when deserializing?

Comment: I have not. Is there an "easier" way than having to go around in my code sending in the SynchronizationContext when the object is created? Or am I just being too lazy :D

Comment: If you're creating the object in the same context in which you wish the event handlers to run, you can set the field to `SynchronizationContext.Current` in the object's constructor, but otherwise, I'm not sure what the best way to go would be.

Comment: In general, I would expect the event raiser to only offer the guarantee that the thread on which the property is changed is the one that the `PropertyChanged` event is raised on (which is what your sample shows). Therefore, I would expect the handler (presumably your UI or a UI binding or a UI binding source) to deal with the synchronizing if it really needs to. Alternatively, be really careful to only make changes from the correct thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So... turns out there's actually a very nice way if you don't mind relying on an extension generating some code for you at compile time. I was using Fody/PropertyChanged anyway, making this a very easy change. This avoids having to a reference to a `SynchronizationContext` in models that really have no business knowing about the UI.

1. First, install [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), available from NuGet.
2. Every class that currently implements `INofityPropertyChanged` should instead have the attribute `[ImplementPropertyChanged]`. The manual implementation should be removed. See the [readme](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki) for more information.
3. A [PropertyChangedNotificationInterceptor](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/NotificationInterception) needs to be implemented. They provide an example for WPF in the wiki; my implementation for a WinForms project:

   ```
   public static class PropertyChangedNotificationInterceptor
   {
       public static SynchronizationContext UIContext { get; set; }

       public static void Intercept(object target, Action onPropertyChangedAction, string propertyName)
       {
           if (UIContext != null)
           {
               UIContext.Post(_ =>
               {
                   onPropertyChangedAction();
               }, null);
           }
           else
           {
               onPropertyChangedAction();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Set `PropertyChangedNotificationInterceptor.UIContext` somewhere. You can put `PropertyChangedNotificationInterceptor.UIContext = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;` in the constructor of your main form.

   The [`Form` constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,52be64ac3517a0a7) goes through the [Control constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,03d2aaba96563a71) and will eventually end up creating the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` if one does not already exist. Therefore, it is safe to capture the `.Current` here. (Note: this might be an implementation detail, and could change in future .NET versions, different platforms, etc.)

Keep in mind that this only works if you only have a single sync context (a single UI thread). If you ever get into the mess of multiple UI threads, *and* require data-binding on more than one, this would get far more complicated. So please don't do that.

Thanks to [Simon Cropp](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2013/02/inotifypropertychanged-worst-interface.html?showComment=1362905979631#c2877374371984976135) for writing `PropertyChanged` and also helping me find this particular feature of it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not lucky and have to use Winforms try using MainForm of your application to invoke handler in UI thread. The bad thing is that you have to include

`using System.Windows.Forms;`

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) return; 
        var mainForm = Application.OpenForms[0];
        if(mainForm == null) return; // No main form - no calls

        if (mainForm.InvokeRequired) 
        {
            // We are not in UI Thread now
            mainform.Invoke(handler, new object[] {
               this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)});
        }
        else
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
        }              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using WPF you can marshal your calls to the UI thread with the Dispatcher.

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>{ 
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Forms.

Comment: @Stephen You can marshal to the UI thread in WinForms by calling invoke on a control, but that's clunky and not very elegant

Comment: An hour of searching... finally - an excellent, clean, concise and working answer (for wpf anyway).  thanks!

Comment: How and what is meant by "App" in this code because this on its own doesn't work.

Comment: When using WPF, App is an alias for the static Application class.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question has already been answered. However i stumbled across the same problem some time ago.
My first approach was very the same than the answer from Dan Busha and others: To invoke the PropertyChanged event on the gui synchronization context.
But in my oppinion this is not the best solution, because your model needs to know of GUI related stuff.
And it would be better that the binding itself is synchronizing with the GUI thread. 
In Windows Forms there is the BindingSource. To make it easy to create DataBindings in the Designer and other binding related stuff.
My idea was to use the BindingSource to synchronize the threads. Basically my idea was to override all OnBlaEvent and invoke them in the GUI Thread.
Just use it like a normal Binding Source.
This is what i came up with:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace System.Windows.Forms.More
{
  [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(BindingSource))]
  public class SynchronizedBindingSource : BindingSource
  {

    #region constructors

    public SynchronizedBindingSource()
    {
      this.SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    public SynchronizedBindingSource(IContainer container)
      : this()
    {
      container?.Add(this);
    }

    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Changed events of binding source will be called from this synchronization context
    /// This is initialized at constructor
    /// </summary>
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public SynchronizationContext SynchronizationContext { get; set; }


    #region thread safe events

    protected override void OnAddingNew(AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnAddingNew(e));
    }

    protected override void OnBindingComplete(BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnBindingComplete(e));
    }

    protected override void OnCurrentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnCurrentChanged(e));
    }

    protected override void OnCurrentItemChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnCurrentItemChanged(e));
    }

    protected override void OnDataError(BindingManagerDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnDataError(e));
    }

    protected override void OnDataMemberChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnDataMemberChanged(e));
    }

    protected override void OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnDataSourceChanged(e));
    }

    protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnListChanged(e));
    }

    protected override void OnPositionChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
      this.InvokeOnUiThread(() => base.OnPositionChanged(e));
    }

    private void InvokeOnUiThread(Action action)
    {
      this.SynchronizationContext?.Post(o => action(), null);
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering whether `InvokeOnUiThread` should handle `SynchronizationContext == null` in some way?

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure about how to handle it. Usually a SynchronizationContext is present when using Windows Forms. However maybe its better to throw a NullPointerException instead of just doing nothing, in case SynchronizationContext is null?